# Escape quotes inside of parentheses

Tags: javascript, escaping

I am using `JSON.stringify` to create the following:

```
{"id":"3172043","Img":"../assets/7/14/NPCgunnerStanding.png","ImgWidth":145,"ImgHeight":210,"Width":"145","Height":"210","Left":649,"Top":165,"Parent":"3172015","MouseOver":"label({HTML: "Gunner"})","Idle":"animate({ rate:100 , pause:4000 })topImage("../assets/img/npc-exclamation3.gif")","MouseOut":"label({})","Proximity":"","Click":"modal({title:"Gunner",iframe: "../assets/7/modals/BEFGunner.php"})"}
```

and storing it in my db. This part is working fine, but when I look it up again I'm getting errors for the object because of the quotes inside of parentheses.

How can I escape just these quotes?

I started to put together a replacer function for the `stringify` call that would check for these, but it started to seem like it would be messy and I was hoping to come up with a way to do it all at once with regex or something.

Please Assist :)

Comment: You can use single quotes as your wrappers, allowing the ones in the data to work just fine.

Comment: or you could add a backslash before the quotes inside your values

Comment: I don't understand. `JSON.stringify()` is giving you a result without the inner double quotes escaped?

Comment: yes it is unfortunately, and I can't use single quotes instead because of the way it's set up

Comment: @Helto: What is the original object you're stringifying? In my browser, `JSON.stringify` does the escaping as expected.

Comment: ...or are you getting the error when trying to *read* the property from the parsed result? You should show the code that is giving you the error.

Comment: @user1689607 The read works fine when I manually escape the quotes in the db, I also am getting the correct string from the stringify after isolating that, so there must be something else going on :(

Comment: There is some regex being applied to all db updates that another dev wrote that must be interfering with this

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape at least

- `"` -> `\"`
- `\\` -> `\\`
- CR -> `\r`
- LF -> `\n`

To do that in JS try this

```
var charToJson = { '"': '\\"', '\\': '\\\\', '\r': '\\r', '\n': '\\n' };

var JSONStringLiteral = '"'
    + myPlainTextString.replace(/[\\\"\r\n]/g, function (c) { return charToJson[c]; })
    + '"';
```

Alternatively, if you're running on a modern browser, `JSON.stringify` should do this for you.

```
JSON.stringify('{"foo":"bar"}') === '"{\\"foo\\":\\"bar\\"}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double Quotes..

```
"label({HTML: \"Gunner\"})"
```

OR use single Quotes inside

```
 "label({HTML: 'Gunner'})"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` like so:

```
{"key":"text (\"blabla\")"}
```

Or for cleaner code:

```
{'key':'text ("blabla")'}
```

But you have not choice if you have both `"` and `'`, like:

```
{"key":"text 'blabla' \"otherblabla\""}
```